# [C++ STL]-pair<vector-iter,int*> - mismatch - no matching function

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

```
int nums[] = { 4096,64,55,23,544,23,44,556,75,33,23,23};
    //nums + sizeof(nums)/sizeof(int)
    pair<vector<int>::iterator,int*> pr;
   pr = mismatch (p6store.begin(),p6store.end(),nums); //ERROR HERE
```

> C:\WS8_SRV\server_aplt\src\include\c++\3.4.2\bits\stl_pair.h In constructor `std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_U1, _U2>&) [with _U1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >, _U2 = int*, _T1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >, _T2 = int*]':
>
> 90 C:\WS8_SRV\server_aplt\src\include\c++\3.4.2\bits\stl_pair.h no matching function for call to `__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >::__normal_iterator(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >&)'

I don't get what is wrong with that snippet

I have included vector,utility and algorithm.

Thanks

EDIT:Complete Code

```
vector<unsigned long long int> p6store(350);

init_sq_generator(0);
generate(p6store.begin(),p6store.end(),sq_generator);

for_each(p6store.begin(),p6store.end(),print_val);
int nums[] = { 4096,64,55,23,544,23,44,556,75,33,23,23};
```

Comment: What's `p6store`? What's `mismatch`? In other words, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: That snippet is not complete. For example p6store is not defined. That's what wrong with that snippet.

Comment: `Can I use mismatch to compare vector which stores ull(unsigned long long) int with an normal int array`  A `vector<T>` and `vector<U>` or array of `U` are two different types.  It doesn't matter if `T` and `U` have similar properties (i.e. integers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::vector<unsigned long long int>` is not the same as `std::vector<int>`

Hence, `std::vector<unsigned long long int>::iterator` is not the same as `std::vector<int>::iterator`.

You should rather use:

```
std:pair<std::vector<unsigned long long int>::iterator,int*> pr;
```

or

```
std::pair<decltype(p6store.begin()),int*> pr;
```

or (the best one):

```
auto pr = std::mismatch(p6store.begin(), p6store.end(), nums);
```

Comment: It worked with ull.I was curious and tried the decltype code and got "35 `p6store' cannot appear in a constant-expression " - "a function call cannot appear in a constant-expression"

Comment: @Yashas Samaga: decltype example: http://ideone.com/huVXDp

Comment: I made a new program with your code, still the same error.Are there any restrictions on it?

Comment: Does your compiler support C++11 ?